# DocPrintJob can't define right mime type

Tags: java, printing, jpeg

1. My CUPS supported:
   [23/Jul/2018:16:03:29 +0300] [Job 80] document-format-supported (30
   values)
2. When i try to sent to print JPG,JPEG **content_type** send
   "File of type application/octet-stream queued by ..."
   instead transform into "image/jpeg".
3. When i try to sent to print PDF and PNG **content_type**, send correct
   "application/pdf" and "image/png" respectively.
4. Classes which used DocPrintJob=UnixPrintJob, PrintService=IPPPrintService
5. When i try to print by **lpr** JPEG file, printer prints a file correctly

==============================================================

```
    PrintServiceAttributeSet printServiceAttributeSet = new HashPrintServiceAttributeSet();
    printServiceAttributeSet.add(new PrinterName( printQueueName, null ));
    PrintService printServices[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( null,
                                                                           printServiceAttributeSet );
    if ( printServices.length != 1 )
    {
        Lib.log.warnf( "Print queue with name %s is not found", printQueueName );
        throw ValidateException.warn( PrintmanMld.PRINT_QUEUE_IS_NOT_FOUND, printQueueName );
    }

    DocPrintJob job = printServices[0].createPrintJob();

    try
    {
        if ( contentStream.available() <= 0 )
        {
            Lib.log.warn("Print file is empty");
            throw ValidateException.warn(PrintmanMld.PRINT_FILE_IS_EMPTY);
        }

        DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc( contentStream, flavor, null );
        job.print( doc, aset );
    }
    catch( PrintException | IOException ex )
    {
        Lib.log.error( ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex );
        throw new ExecutionContextException(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow. This looks like a pretty good post but can you please start any posts by *clearly* stating the problem that you are trying to solve. [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Cheers!

Comment: No problem i will try to improve my "Stack Overflow" posting skill

Comment: Caution:  [InputStream.available() does not indicate end of file, it only reports how many bytes can be read without blocking.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available())